# LocalStorage value not shown in other html page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a `index.html` page where I set `userid` in `localStorage` as below

**Index.html**

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id='user_id' required tabindex="1" name="user_id" autofocus autocomplete=off placeholder="User Name">
 </div>
 <input class="user_login_submit" type="submit"  id='btnLogin' tabindex="3" name="login_btnSubmit" tabindex='3' onclick='validateLogin();'value="LOGIN" />

<script>
function validateLogin() {
    var userid = document.getElementById('user_id').value;
    localStorage.setItem("userID", "Welcome, " + userid);
}
</script>
```

Now I wanted to show this `userid` in `navbar` i.e. `nav.html` page, Please note it only contains `navbar` code no any other header or body part,

**nav.html**

```
   <li><a href="#" id="profileDDL"style="text-transform:capitalize;opactiy:0.4;font-weight:bolder">
    </a></li>
    <script> 
                   $(function() {
                    $('#profileDDL').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("userID");
                });
       </script>
```

and now ,  I wanted to load this `nav.html` page inside `user_home.html` or any other html page with  `userID` from `localStorage` , `navbar` is loaded fine but not the `localStorage` value.

**user_home.html**

```
    <body>
        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <div id="nav-placeholder">

        </div>
        <!--end of Navigation bar-->

        <script>
        $(function(){
        $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
});
</script>
    </body>
```

I hope you understand the what is my problem.I'm stuck here.

Comment: your problem is to pass the value of userid from one page to another?

Comment: yes, I wanted to show userID everywhere with nav-bar

Comment: `$('#profileDDL')` returns a jQueery object, which has no resemblance to do with a DOM element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
$('#profileDDL').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("userID");
```

to

```
$('#profileDDL').html(localStorage.getItem("userID"));
```

Comment: ... because $(...) is a jQueery object, not a DOM element (explanation goes a long way)